# I have find out the mismatch between the two tables in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables :

1st table has 2 columns :   A   Ticket Id    B  Combo

Ticket Id has the ticket numbers and Combo column has the Incident Status values and these values can be same for many tickets ids.

2nd Tables has 2 columns :  A  Compare Combo  B Match

Compare combo has the Incident Status values and Match column has Yes or No.

Now we need to check each Combo value of first table with the Compare column of second table and if the Match column has the value Yes then it should be there in the BI report.

The things I have tried

1. `LookupValue`: Giving error that only single value is allowed.
2. `If`: Not allowed because there is no relationship between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply need to create a relationship between the two tables on field `Combo`, then filter your report / visualisation based on field `Table2[Match] = Yes`